# Wiring new light fixture from receptacle circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am wanting to wire a new light fixture in a location where branching from room's overhead lighting circuit is difficult (because of stud locations) but branching from a nearby receptacle box looks relatively easy.

Is there any reason I shouldn't take the easy path here? I'll match the 12 gauge wiring coming into the receptacle box, but even with that would there be any overloading concerns? Or is this a situation where I just need to label things clearly at the breaker box and call it a day?

Answer (score 1):

Lights do not take much power(unless very many), especially the LED types.

I think maybe bathroom/kitchen receptacles might not be allowed now to power lights, but other rooms are.

Will need a 12/3 cable to the wall switch, since new switches require to have neutral now, usually just capped off.

Comment: *Either* 12/2 from receptacle to switch, 12/2 from switch to light fixture *or* 12/2 from receptacle to fixture and 12/3 from fixture to switch. Given the up/down involved, I would think receptacle, up wall to switch, up wall to ceiling/fixture would make sense, but it will depend on relative location of each piece.